# Propaer way to access object received in Request.Form[]

Tags: c#, jquery

I am getting some string data along with files & i can access file like this `Request.Files[0]` but question is how can i access value of string objects? I am already trying to access it like this: `Request.Form["url"]` but seems not returns appropriate data. Please tell me how can i access `Request.Form["url"]` in a proper way.

Jquery Payload:

```
//FormData
            var formData = new FormData();

            $(".wholeBar").each(function (key, value) {
                var findFiles = $(this).find(".hpicFile"); //find the element
                var file = findFiles[0].files[0]; //get the actual file object
                formData.append('files[]', file); //append all files to formData

                

               // console.log(value);
                var urlInput = $(this).find(".hurl");
                formData.set("url", urlInput);
                console.log(urlInput.val());

            });
           

            //Ajax request
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Controller/Upload",
                type: "POST",
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                data: formData, //Send form Data
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response)
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
                }
            });
```

C#:

```
var ddd = Request.Files[0];

                var fff = Request.Form["url"];

                //foreach (var item in fff)
                //{
                //    var aaa  = item.ToString();
                //}
                return Json("ok");
```

[image: c#]

Comment: The bug is likely in your JS or client side. Please share the client side logic, and also please show us the payload being submitted to the server (using Chrome Developer Tools -> Network).

Comment: @mjwills Jquery code added.

Comment: And the payload?

Comment: `formData.set("url", urlInput);` You can't add a DOM element like that. What is `urlInput`? A textbox?

Comment: `urlInput` is just string for example: `http://example.com` as just string

Comment: That is not true. `urlInput.val()` might be that - but not `urlInput`.

Comment: ohh i got my mistake! Thanks @mjwills

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can set string Data in below format in Jquery

var formData = new FormData();

```
        var obj = {
            Username: "user5",
            Email: "em@example.com"
        };

        formData.set("data", obj);
```

and Receive it on Controller side as below format

### VB.Net

Dim objUser As cls_User = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of cls_User )(Request("obj"))

### C#

cls_User objUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<cls_User>(Request("obj"));

You need to create a class to capture the data coming from FormData() and then use the same object to retrieve it from (Request("obj") to Dim objUser As cls_User